# Remove all added products in GA Enhanced E-commerce

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I have set up GA Enhanced ECommerce. I can fire off add, remove, detail, etc... events for my products. Everything works as expected.

When a user adds several items to the cart then abandons the process, I want GA to be notified that all of the items were removed. Currently I have to fire  a GA 'remove' message for each item. Is there a call I can make to GA to remove all items from the cart?

I noticed that google ecommerce (not google enhanced ecommerce) offers an `ecommerce:clear`, something like this would be ideal.

Comment: I guess you could do this in numerous ways, but where in would the logic lie? When do you decide a cart has been abandoned? Seeing as you have cart abandonment as a metric within GA already, I am not really sure how that added information would help.

Answer (score -1):

Well according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#cart) you can make a single call with all the items on it. You just need to add all the products on the **products array**.

Hope it helps!